# Retrieve event content object link in bolt

Tags: bolt-cms, ifttt

I'm writing an extension which send notifications to IFTTT when a content is published on my bolt install.

Using callbacks in my extension, I can get the `\Bolt\Content` object linked to the raised event but how can I get its permalink ?

Here is the callback code :

```
public function postSaveCallback(\Bolt\Events\StorageEvent $event)
{
    $content = $event->getContent();

    // Payload 
    $payload = array(
        'value1' => $content->get('title'),
        'value2' => $content->get('link')
    );

    $this->sendRequest("published", $payload);
}
```

Variable `$content->title` is retrieved and has the given value, but `$content->link` is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it.

link is not a variable but a function defined in `Bolt\Content`.

So, I just need to call `'value2' => $content->link()`